# Python Twisted does not work on Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, twisted, pydev

I installed Twisted for Python and I am trying to build a simple server on Eclipse and I am getting the following error:

ImportError: No module named zope.interface

I'm not sure how to correct this.  Doesn't Twisted install all of the dependencies first?

Comment: How are you making sure that Eclipse sets the correct PYTHONPATH to find those dependencies?

Comment: How did you install Twisted?  How did you set up Eclipse?  How did you set up PyDev?  What platform are you on?  Can you import twisted *without* eclipse involved?  Please provide enough information that someone could at least try to reproduce your setup so we know what's going on.

Comment: I dont think zope.interface is installed automatically, you have to do it yourself (`pip install zope.interface`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you:

1. Have PyDev installed
2. Have twisted / zope.interface installed and in your PYTHONPATH.
3. Have configured your eclipse project as a python/pydev project.
4. Have configured the interpreter in the Eclipse environment (Pydev settings).